# Deploy retrained inception SavedModel to google cloud ml engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to deploy a retrained version of the inception model on google cloud ml-engine. Gathering informations from the [SavedModel documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md), this [reference](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic.html), and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968628/how-do-i-convert-a-cloudml-alpha-model-to-a-savedmodel) of rhaertel80, I exported successfully my retrained model to a SavedModel, uploaded it to a bucket and tried to deploy it to a ml-engine version.

This last task actually creates a version, but it outputs this error:

`Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Error loading the model: Unexpected error when loading the model"`

And when I try to get predictions from the model via commandline I get this error message: 
`"message": "Field: name Error: Online prediction is unavailable for this version. Please verify that CreateVersion has completed successfully."`

I have made several attempts, trying different `method_name` and `tag` options but none worked.

The code added to the original inception code is

```
  ### DEFINE SAVED MODEL SIGNATURE

  in_image = graph.get_tensor_by_name('DecodeJpeg/contents:0')
  inputs = {'image_bytes': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(in_image)}

  out_classes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
  outputs = {'prediction': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(out_classes)}

  signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs=inputs,
      outputs=outputs,
      method_name='tensorflow/serving/predict'
  )


  ### SAVE OUT THE MODEL

  b = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder('new_export_dir')
  b.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                 [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                 signature_def_map={'predict_images': signature})
  b.save()
```

Another consideration that might help:
I have used an exported a `trained_graph.pb` with `graph_def.SerializeToString()` to get the predictions locally and it works fine, but when I substitute it with the `saved_model.pb` it fails.

Any suggestions on what the issue might be?

Comment: would you mind sharing a sample request.json that matches your signature?  I am struggling with this error.  `prediction_lib.PredictionError: (4, "Exception during running the graph: Cannot feed value of shape (1,) for Tensor u'DecodeJpeg/contents:0', which has shape '()'")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your signature_def_map, use the key 'serving_default', which is defined in [`signature_constants`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/signature_constants) as `DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY`:

```
b.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                               [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                               signature_def_map={'serving_default': signature})
```