# Tensorflow model import to Java

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have been trying to import and make use of my trained model (Tensorflow, Python) in Java.

I was able to save the model in Python, but encountered problems when I try to make predictions using the same model in Java.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/szingerpeter/ff76df0b5014f93722c977139beaf921), you can see the python code for initializing, training, saving the model.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/szingerpeter/b468f35c76d054c5c9aeb22adc9e2bb2), you can see the Java code for importing and making predictions for input values.

The error message I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_7
     [[Node: Variable_7/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_7"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_7)]]
    at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:285)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:235)
    at org.tensorflow.examples.Identity_import.main(Identity_import.java:35)
```

I believe, the problem is somewhere in the python code, but I was not able to find it.

Comment: I used [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java) as inspiration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Java `importGraphDef()` function is only importing the computational graph (written by `tf.train.write_graph` in your Python code), it isn't loading the values of trained variables (stored in the checkpoint), which is why you get an error complaining about uninitialized variables.

The [TensorFlow SavedModel format](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model) on the other hand includes all information about a model (graph, checkpoint state, other metadata) and to use in Java you'd want to use [`SavedModelBundle.load`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/SavedModelBundle) to create session initialized with the trained variable values.

To export a model in this format from Python, you might want to take a look at a related question [Deploy retrained inception SavedModel to google cloud ml engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001719/deploy-retrained-inception-savedmodel-to-google-cloud-ml-engine/43002175)

In your case, this should amount to something like the following in Python:

```
def save_model(session, input_tensor, output_tensor):
  signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs = {'input': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_tensor)},
    outputs = {'output': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(output_tensor)},
  )
  b = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder('/tmp/model')
  b.add_meta_graph_and_variables(session,
                                 [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                 signature_def_map={tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature})
  b.save()
```

And invoke that via `save_model(session, x, yhat)`

And then in Java load the model using:

```
try (SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load("/tmp/mymodel", "serve")) {
  // b.session().run(...)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Warning: While this will work in Java, TF currently does not support loading a SavedModel in Android. Found this out the hard way. :/

Comment: Instead, see issues #12750 or #13079, or see https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models

Comment: does this work with loading models from gcs bucket ?? i am not able to use savedmodelbundle to load models and variables froma  gcs bucket

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, Deeplearning4j lets you import models trained on TensorFlow with Keras 1.0 (Keras 2.0 support is on the way).

https://deeplearning4j.org/model-import-keras

We also built a library called Jumpy, which is a wrapper around Numpy arrays and Pyjnius that uses pointers instead of copying data, which makes it more efficient than Py4j when dealing with tensors.

https://deeplearning4j.org/jumpy

Comment: Thanks!

I was about building a GAN in Tensorflow, and as far as I know DL4J doesn't support GANs in general, that's why I was looking for a workaround being able to use a GAN trained with Tensorflow and ran on JVM.

Comment: when will keras support be released?  i see the PR is in.  It'd be super convenient to get the conv1d layer support

Comment: RIP Jumpy. Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your python-model will certainly fail at this:

```
sess.run(init) #<---this will fail
save_model(sess)
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction - y))

#accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(error, 'float'))
print('Error:', error)
```

`init` is not defined in the model - I'm unsure what you want achieve at this place, but that should give you a starting point