# Job not generating /export directory

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm following [the guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction#deploy_a_model_to_support_prediction) to deploy a model having previously generated the job:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training testX 
    --job-dir="gs://testxxx/run1"
    --package-path=trainer
    --module-name=trainer.task
    --region us-central1
    --runtime-version=1.0
```

When I see the contents of the output path, I don't see the "export" dir, only this:

```
$ gsutil ls -r $OUTPUT_PATH
gs://testxxx/run1/:
gs://testxxx/run1/
gs://testxxx/run1/packages/:
gs://testxxx/run1/packages/fcd2eee0ae2b155ccb3b644c26cf75d6cf81b2dd068122690c9a4baf8ff8e8f5/:
gs://testxxx/run1/packages/fcd2eee0ae2b155ccb3b644c26cf75d6cf81b2dd068122690c9a4baf8ff8e8f5/trainer-0.1.tar.gz
```

Am I forgetting any step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you submit is responsible for exporting the model. You can find an example on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43001719); please reference [SavedModel docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md).

The inputs and outputs of your model will of course be specific to your model, but for convenience (and slightly modified), here's the code from that post:

```
### BUILD THE PREDICTION GRAPH
in_image = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=(None,))
out_classes = build_prediction_graph(in_image)

### DEFINE SAVED MODEL SIGNATURE
inputs = {'image_bytes': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(in_image)}
outputs = {'prediction': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(out_classes)}
signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=outputs,
    method_name='tensorflow/serving/predict'
)

### SAVE OUT THE MODEL
b = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder('new_export_dir')
b.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                               [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                               signature_def_map={'serving_default': signature})
b.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, will check the documentation on SavedModel