# Empty variables folder after building retrained inception SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to export my retrained inception model. I've read this almost similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001719/deploy-retrained-inception-savedmodel-to-google-cloud-ml-engine) and resources mentioned there as well.
But after exporting the graph, the `variables` **folder is empty** which should contains files that hold the serialized variables of the graphs (saved_model.pb is created correctly I'd say).

I'm using TensorFlow 1.2.1 & Python 3.5.2.

Actually I've put a simple `print(tf.trainable_variables())` inside the session, but it's an empty list.

Here's my function to export the graph:

```
def export_tf_model(graph_path, export_dir):    
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(graph_path, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        g = sess.graph

        # print variables
        print(tf.trainable_variables())

        in_image = g.get_tensor_by_name('DecodeJpeg/contents:0')
        inputs = {'images': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(in_image)}

        out_classes = g.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        outputs = {'scores': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(out_classes)}

        signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs=inputs,
            outputs=outputs,
            method_name=signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
        )

        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess,
            [tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature},
        )

        builder.save()
```

I cannot figure out where could be the problem?

I've tried `mnist_saved_model.py` from official tutorial and it works fine exporting both graph & variables. But I see that it's training and exporting. Is it necessary to do training before exporting graph? If yes how should I do it for

Comment: Does `print(tf.trainable_variables())` print anything?

Comment: @mrry no it's an empty list. Actually I guess I've found the problem. When I export the model during training it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to the frozen `pb` model, for variables have been converted into constants during freezing graph (See document [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models#how_do_you_get_a_model_you_can_use_on_mobile)). Use initial `ckpt` model file instead and maybe these threads help: [# 1938](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1988), [#2045](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2045)